# Iron-router's this.render function does not render

Tags: meteor, iron-router

As the title says, this.render does not render a template it's provided with. This is the code in `router.js`:

```js
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'main'
});
Router.route('/', function(){
  this.render('postsList');
});
```

The file containing the layout template, `main.html`:

```html
<template name='main'>
    <div class='container'>
        <header class='navbar'>
            <div class='navbar-inner'>
                <a class='brand' href='/'>MyApp</a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id='main' class='row-fluid'>
            {{> yield}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the file containing the postsList template which is passed to `this.render()` function

```xml
<template name='postsList'>
    <div class='posts'>
        {{#each posts}}
            {{> postItem}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

So when I go to `localhost:3000/` the page displays only the `main` template and not the `postsList` template. However, there is no error, unless I completely remove `Router.route(...)`, at which point it will display the standard 'route not found' error.
Also, I tried not using the global template, but a route template, by removing `Router.configure(...)` and adding `this.layout('main')` to `Router.route(...)`. The browser then displays nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. I also came across this issue. The iron:router package seems to be missing the ejson dependancy.

Add the ejson to your app and it should work.

`meteor add ejson`

I'm sure when iron:router is updated this will be resolved.